# generating Deployment Descriptor (web.xml) in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, web.xml

I'm using gradle for my spring projects and need to copy and paste the content of `web.xml` (and also other xml based spring configurations) every single time! Is there anyway to auto generate these files, like the way it can be done in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the best way I know till now is creating a New Template file for different xml files:

`Right Click on project > New > Edit File Template > ...`

Answer (score 6):

The 1st answer is great way for creating own file template. But Intellij has already generated default templates for `web.xml` and Spring file.

As for now, by using `alt + ins`, Intellij provides `JSP Tag Library Descriptor`, `New Faces Config File`, and `Spring Config` which is helpful for `xml based spring configurations`.

And for `web.xml` file, `Project Structure (ctrl + alt + shift + s) > Facets > Deployment Descriptors > + > web.xml` will generate a `web.xml` file for you.

Comment: By now idea 2020.2, you have to create the web module in `Modules` side menu, and put the right web.xml path to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the IntelliJ IDEA documentation you can generate deployment descriptors using the web facet settings: [Managing deployment descriptors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-application-support.html#d1788100e305)
- At least since version 2016.1